# Refactor method/constructor parameters to insert the whole object in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to refactor the code so that the whole object `input` is passed as a parameter instead of its parts `input.getI(), input.getJ()`.

I could easily do the opposite with `Extract Parameter` action, but how do I refactor it like this across the code base, in IntelliJ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo input = new Foo(0, 1);

    //What I have:
    new Bar(input.getI(), input.getJ());
    print(input.getI(), input.getJ());

    //What I want: 
    //new Bar(input);
    //print(input);
}

public static void print(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println(i + j);
}

public static class Foo {
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public Foo(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }
}

public static class Bar {
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public Bar(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your best hope here would be to refactor the constructor `Foo` itself, and change it to one parameter.  If you're lucky, IntelliJ will prompt you at each change letting you alter the method calls.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just added a class Bar to make it clearer...

Comment: Are the parameters always consecutive and named similarly? I wonder if a string based regex find / replace, although perhaps a little hacky, could be the best solution here? Failing that I have written a simple plugin in the past to handle simple refactoring needs.

Comment: @vikingsteve Too hacky, I would like something that can be used in a complex codebase without much thinking. Structural replace can handle non-consecutive parameters just fine. A plugin would be ideal.

Comment: The plugin is quite easy to write. You just need to add an action in the "Refactoring" menu, and then use the cursor position as a context (perhaps the constructor for `Boo`) - thereafter use refactoring operations to tranverse the AST and make the changes to the code.

Comment: @Meo if you look on my github I have some plugin examples https://github.com/Steve-Murphy/

Comment: @vikingsteve oh I have some examples too :) https://github.com/krasa/translator-generator-intellij-plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add overloads for the method/constructor you want:

```
public static void print(Foo foo) { ... }
public Bar(Foo foo) { ... }
```

Then use structural search and replace (Edit > Find > Replace Structurally) to replace:

```
print($f$.getI(), $f$.getJ());
```

with

```
print($f$);
```

(If necessary, constrain `$f$` to be of type `Foo` by clicking "Edit Variables", pick `f` from the list, and set "Expected Type (regexp)" to "Foo")

Similarly, replace:

```
new Bar($f$.getI(), $f$.getJ());
```

with

```
new Bar($f$);
```

Answer (score 2):

First extract a method with **Ctrl+Alt+M** with just the call to `print(input.getI(), input.getJ());`

IntelliJ will extract the method with the whole object as `print(Foo foo)`

Then inline the old `public static void print(int i, int j)` method with **Ctrl+Alt+N**

Comment: This works for methods, not constructors. But yes, this is the right way for methods, which was half of the question.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the `Bar` class definition then right-click and select
   refactor.
2. Select Change Signature
3. Remove the old parameters(-)
4. Add the new Parameter using the fully qualified name(+)